# Can anyone help me in bulkyfying this trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

```
trigger CPCompetitor on Opportunity (after insert,after update)
{
   List<SP_Product_Item__c> spproduct = new List<SP_Product_Item__c>();
   List<Id> accId =new List<Id>();
   List<Sales_Plan__c> splist = new  List<Sales_Plan__c>();
  if(Trigger.isAfter) 
  {
     for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
       {
          List<Product2> prolist = new List<Product2>();
         prolist  = [select id, Product_Type__C,Producer__c from product2 where id =: opp.Switched_to_Product__c];

       for(Product2 p : prolist)
        {
            system.debug('*'+p.Producer__C);
            if(p.Product_Type__C  == 'Competitor Seeds Product' || p.Product_Type__C  == 'Competitor CP Product')
           {  
              splist =[select id, account__c  from Sales_Plan__c where Account__c in (select AccountId  from Opportunity where Switched_to_Product__c=: opp.Switched_to_Product__c)];
                     for(Sales_Plan__c s : splist){
                       SP_Product_Item__c sp = new  SP_Product_Item__c();
                       sp.Account__c = s.account__c;
                       sp.Sales_Plan__c = s.id;
                       sp.Product__c = p.id;
                       if(p.Product_Type__C  == 'Competitor CP Product')
                       {
                            sp.Type__c  = 'CP Competitor'; 
                       }
                       else    
                       {
                            sp.Type__c = 'Seeds Competitor'; 
                       }
                       system.debug('***'+p.id);
                       system.debug('*'+ s.id);
                       system.debug('*'+ s.account__c);        
                       spproduct.add(sp);
                 }

           }
   }






}
    insert spproduct;
    system.debug('*****' );
}
}
```

Comment: What in this trigger are you struggling with to bulkify ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke as u can see Soql is written inside the loop. its executing 17 times.

Comment: Yes I can see that, but that doesn't tell me why you're not sure how to fix it :-).  Because that is where i'd like to help you.. to help you understand, rather than just write updated code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I just used a map to hold the Opportunity objects from Trigger and your 2nd SOQL query really has no requirement to be inside the for loop. I took it out.

PS: There could be some error with the number of brackets, make the changes accordingly. I didn't run it.

```
List<SP_Product_Item__c> spproduct = new List<SP_Product_Item__c>();
   List<Id> accId =new List<Id>();
   List<Sales_Plan__c> splist = new  List<Sales_Plan__c>();
  if(Trigger.isAfter) 
  {
     for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
       {

    Map<Id, Opportunity> stpMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    stpMap.add(opp.Switched_to_Product__c, opp);
       }
          List<Product2> prolist = new List<Product2>();
         prolist  = [select id, Product_Type__C,Producer__c from product2 where id in :stpMap.keySet()];
    splist =[select id, account__c  from Sales_Plan__c where Account__c in (select AccountId  from Opportunity where Switched_to_Product__c in : stpMap.keySet())];


       for(Product2 p : prolist)
        {
            system.debug('*'+p.Producer__C);
            if(p.Product_Type__C  == 'Competitor Seeds Product' || p.Product_Type__C  == 'Competitor CP Product')
           {  

                     for(Sales_Plan__c s : splist){
                       SP_Product_Item__c sp = new  SP_Product_Item__c();
                       sp.Account__c = s.account__c;
                       sp.Sales_Plan__c = s.id;
                       sp.Product__c = p.id;
                       if(p.Product_Type__C  == 'Competitor CP Product')
                       {
                            sp.Type__c  = 'CP Competitor'; 
                       }
                       else    
                       {
                            sp.Type__c = 'Seeds Competitor'; 
                       }
                       system.debug('***'+p.id);
                       system.debug('*'+ s.id);
                       system.debug('*'+ s.account__c);        
                       spproduct.add(sp);
                 }

           }
   }


}
    insert spproduct;
    system.debug('*****' );
}
```

Comment: Your query on `Sales_Plan__c` should be using `stpMap.keySet()` as well. You can also add the following where condition to the `product2` query `where Product_Type__in ('Competitor Seeds Product', 'Competitor CP Product')` to stop it returning records that are not needed.

Comment: Also you are probably creating too many `SP_Product_Item__c` records. In the original code if there was 5 `Product2` records returned from the query and each one had a single `Sales_Plan__c` record then there would be 5 `SP_Product_Item__c` records created. Your solution would create 25 `SP_Product_Item__c`  records

Comment: Ya both comments are valid. As I mentioned in the Answer as well, I didnt run it. I just focused on the SOQL queries. Thanks Mate!